# Lamba calls always triggering fallback intent ? How to authorize botium with amzon lex IdentifypoolID?

Tags: aws-lambda

I am using botium for my chatbot which is built on top of Amazon lex.

For normal intents, it is recognized properly from the botium emulator

For the intents which invoke lambda calls triggers default fallback intent always.

I am suspecting it is because of aws config credentials which I am using to authenticate the client side(CognitoIdentifyPoolId)
AWS.config.region = 'us-east-1'; // Region
AWS.config.credentials = new AWS.CognitoIdentityCredentials({
IdentityPoolId: 'us-east-1:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
});

I don't know how to pass it from botium json. Please help me to solve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Identity Pools are not supported yet.

Best you can now, to add access to Lambda for Botium user. Is it acceptable for you?